# how could I drag my photo to another dropbox after my photo has been seen previewed?

Tags: javascript, html

what I would like to do is that the preview becomes draggable and moves to another dropbox

make img source" " moves(drag) to another dropbox area

````
<script>
function handleFiles(files) {
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    const file = files[i];

    if (!file.type.startsWith('image/')){ continue }

    const img = document.createElement("img");
    img.classList.add("obj");
    img.file = file;
    preview.appendChild(img); // Assuming that "preview" is the div output where the content will be displayed.

    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(aImg) { return function(e) { aImg.src = e.target.result; }; })(img);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}```
</script>
````

How could I move to another area after my picture is in the preview

Answer (score 0):

Using the java script display the image in div called 'preview'. and enable the functionality to drag the image in Drop Box container using the **jQuery draggable & droppable** function.

[image]

```js
window.onload = function(){
 
 //For example put some image in array
 arrayfile = ['https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg', 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_girl.jpg'];
 handleFiles(arrayfile);
 function handleFiles(files) {
   for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  const file = files[i];
  var img = document.createElement("IMG");
  img.setAttribute("src",file);
  img.classList.add("child");
  img.setAttribute("width", "304");
  img.setAttribute("height", "228");
  img.setAttribute("alt", "image alt");
  img.setAttribute("width", "100");
        img.setAttribute("height", "100");
  //append the image in preview div
  document.getElementById('preview').appendChild(img); 
   }
 }
 
 
 //Use the jquery draggable & droppable function
 $(".child").draggable({
  revert: true
 });

 //use container to drop the image
 $(".container").droppable({
    accept: '.child',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
  ui.helper.data('dropped', true);
  $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
    }

  });
  
}
```

```css
.container{
border:1px solid grey;
    width: 250px; /*can be in percentage also.*/
    height: 250px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
 float:left;
 margin-left:20px;
 
}
.child {
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 
 <!-- Preview div---->
 <div id="preview" class="container" target="child1">
 </div>
  
 <!-- container to drop the Preview Image -->
    <div class="container">

    </div>
```